# How to handle next and previous button in the MPMoviePlayerViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I am getting all events of the player by this notification `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange`, but not getting the next/previous event/action.

Can we handle all actions with the `Now playing` info in the background of application with this player?

Please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for edit, but also provide the solution if you have got please.

Answer (score 0):

`MPMoviePlayerController`, post only `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification` even when stop, previous and next buttons are clicked. You cannot find directly which button is clicked.

For this you can create your own custom control with custom button actions, from this you can detect easily which button is clicked.

**NOTE**: Before creating the custom control you must set the player's controlStyle property to MPMovieControlStyleNone to hide the default controls.

Comment: Thanks Yogesh,
I know the same, but is there any way to find or hide just previous, next button so I could add my custom button as the overlay.

Comment: I presume we can hide all the controls, not specifically for previous and next button.

Comment: Thanks Yogesh. I am still looking for the really good solution. Could it be possible with AVPlayerViewController>